# How to get list of Leads list views?

Tags: apex, list-view

How can I get the list of all Lead list views?

[image: screenshot]

Also, how can I get the people from a particular list by means of Apex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize an [`ApexPages.StandardSetController`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_methods.htm) with a query on a particular type, you can use the set controller's `getListViewOptions()` method to obtain a list (in the form of a `List<SelectOption>`) of the list views for that object. The value of each `SelectOption` is the Id of a list view that can be passed to `setFilterId()` to filter the Set Controller according to that list view's criteria.

Jitendra Zaa has a pretty clear [example](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/listview-filter-in-apex-with-paging-and-navigation/) of how to use this technique.

Comment: Thanks David, i will test it now and let you know, but seems exactly what i need so far.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have selected Recently Viewed List.

You need to change the drop down to list all list.

[image: List view]

Comment: Thanks Santanu, my fault i didn't describe my question better. I ment in apex.